# Как считать данные из файла в массив?

Tags: java

> В файле хранятся координаты вершин четырехугольника в порядке обхода
>   фигуры по часовой стрелке в виде:
>
> <координата x1> <координата y1>     <координата x2> <координата y2>
>     <координата x3> <координата y3>     <координата x4> <координата y4>
>
> ```
> Например: 4 5
>           3 6
>           7 1
>           8 9 
>       Считаем, что полученные из файла вершины гарантированно образуют выпуклый четырехугольник.   Написать программу, которая
> ```
>
> считывает координаты из файла.

Как из этих считанных строк сделать один общий массив. Я пытался сделать так:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            BufferedReader readerFileName = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String fileName = readerFileName.readLine();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line;

            int[] arr = new int[8];
            int i = 0;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                String[] a = line.split(" ");
                arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(a[0]);
                arr[i++] = Integer.parseInt(a[1]);
                i++;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Выдаёт такой массив `[5, 0, 6, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0]`. Почему? Или подскажите более оптимальный способ. Очень долго копался с этим, но никак не доходит.

Comment: в чем ошибка то, значения не те?

Comment: Stranger in the Q, из строки выписались координаты по y-кам и заняли индексы x-сов, а x-сы вообще в значении 0 и на индексах y

Comment: Потому что оператор `i++` - постфиксный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    String[] a = line.split(" ");
    arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(a[0]);
    arr[i++] = Integer.parseInt(a[1]);
    i++;
}
```

оператор `i++` - постфиксный. Семантически это операция get and increment, т.е. сперва берется текущее значение `i`, а лишь затем увеличивается на единицу.

> i = 0

```
arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(a[0]); //arr[0] = 4
arr[i++] = Integer.parseInt(a[1]); //arr[0] = 5; i = i + 1;
```

и т.д.

Замените `i++` на `++i` и всё будет хорошо.